# Cookie or session based welcome message like stackoverflow

Tags: php, session, cookies

I already coded the welcome message bar for my wordpress website. Its working now. But everytime user load a page it shows.

I want to display that welcome message bar only when the user visit first time. If user close it then it shouldn't display until he leaves the site like stackoverflow. I believe stackoverflow uses session based notification.

Can anyone help me with the php code?

This is how my current code looks like

```
<div class="welcome">
            <a class="close" href="#">x</a>
            <p><strong>Hello stranger!</strong> Welcome to example.com. Register or login to get started</p>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use Session for this.

Try bellow code.

```
    <?php
    if(!isset($_SESSION["LOADED"]))
    {
    $_SESSION["LOADED"] = true;
    ?>
    <div class="welcome">
                <a class="close" href="#">x</a>
                <p><strong>Hello stranger!</strong> 
Welcome to example.com. Register or login to get started</p>
              </div>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
```

Make sure you start session at the top of your page.

```
session_start();
```